# Unmarried couple moving to Zurich

Tags: relocation, switzerland

At the end of this year we are planning to move to Zurich, we are an unmarried couple without children, both from EU.

I've received an offer from a Swiss company and expect to receive contract of indefinite duration for roughly 100K CHF.
Based on that I think I might be granted a B permit.

My gf at the moment of arrival probably will be unemployed.

Do I have sign Verpflichtungserklärung to get her same permit as me or any other than L for 3 months?

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid that this is more or less a preliminary answer with some research pointers rather than a comprehensive answer to your question.  I don't have personal experience with the Swiss implementation of its obligations related to the EU freedom of movement directive, but I do have a fair amount of experience with the directive's application in the EU itself.

The first thing to note is that according to the [residence permits page](https://www.ch.ch/en/renewal-overview-swiss-residence-permit/) at www.ch.ch (a great domain name, I must say), is the list of permits that apply to EU and EFTA nationals:

> - Permit L EU/EFTA (short-term residence permit)
> - Permit B EU/EFTA (residence permit)
> - Permit C EU/EFTA (settlement permit)
> - Permit Ci EU/EFTA (residence permit with gainful employment)
> - Permit G EU/EFTA (cross-border commuter permit)

They then have a link to a page with contact information for the cantonal immigration authorities.  The Zürich office is on the web at https://ma.zh.ch/internet/sicherheitsdirektion/migrationsamt/de/home.html.

There (if you read German) you can find, by following two links for [Einreise & Aufenthalt](https://ma.zh.ch/internet/sicherheitsdirektion/migrationsamt/de/einreise_aufenthalt/einreise_aufenthalt.html), a link in the right-side navigation menu for [EU EFTA-Personen & Personenfreizügigkeit](https://ma.zh.ch/internet/sicherheitsdirektion/migrationsamt/de/einreise_aufenthalt/einreise_aufenthalt/eu_efta-personenpersonenfreizuegigkeit.html).

The directive applies not only to spouses and other legal family,  but also to "the partner with whom the Union citizen has a durable relationship, duly attested" (Article (3)(2)(b); in German: *des Lebenspartners, mit dem der Unionsbürger eine ordnungsgemäß bescheinigte dauerhafte Beziehung eingegangen ist).*  States are free to define this phrase, however; for example, the UK requires the partners to have at least two years of cohabitation.

I do not know how Switzerland applies this phrase, and I did not see any evidence of the word "Beziehung" on their web pages.  Similarly, the federal site's [English-language page on the subject](https://www.ch.ch/en/family-reunification-eu-efta/) does not mention that route.  But if they *do* recognize such relationships, and if yours qualifies, that will certainly be the best way to get permission for her to move to Switzerland with you, short of entering into a registered partnership or getting married.

If she cannot qualify based on your relationship, she may be able to qualify as a [self-sufficient person](https://www.ch.ch/en/retirement-or-study-switzerland/) (back to the federal site):

> Persons who are not gainfully employed (e.g. retirees and students) may remain in Switzerland if the following conditions are met:
>
> - They have adequate financial resources to cover the cost of living in Switzerland so as to ensure that they will not become dependent on welfare benefits, and
> - They have a health insurance policy that also includes accident coverage.
> - Students must also show the letter confirming that they have been admitted to a recognised educational institution (confirmation of enrolment).
>
> Stays of up to 90 days within a six-month period do not require authorisation. For longer stays, foreign nationals have to register with the cantonal migration office as a non-employed person. The corresponding EU/EFTA residence permit will remain valid for a period of five years (for students, the permit will remain valid for the duration of education and training or will remain valid for one year and be renewed at one-year intervals). These residence permits will be renewed automatically as long as the abovementioned criteria are still met.

You might be able to make a formal pledge of support in that case, but the site does not seem to indicate it as a possibility.  You asked

> Do I have sign Verpflichtungserklärung to get her same permit as me or any other than L for 3 months?

If she can get a permit based on your relationship, then probably not.  From the [family reunification factsheet (PDF)](https://www.sem.admin.ch/dam/data/sem/eu/fza/personenfreizuegigkeit/factsheets/fs-familiennachzug-e.pdf):

> If the main entitled person is an employee , then the right to family reunification is not contingent upon that person's financial situation.

In fact, in any event, she does not need *any* permit to stay for up to three months.  From the [free movement factsheet (PDF)](https://www.sem.admin.ch/dam/data/sem/eu/fza/personenfreizuegigkeit/factsheets/fs-uebersicht-fza-e.pdf):

> No permit is needed for stays in Switzerland lasting less than three months, either as a tourist or an economically inactive person.